# MySQL and fputcsv PHP fields delimiter not working

Tags: php, mysql, fputcsv

Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('field1', 'field2'),';','"');
mysql_connect('localhost', 'usr', 'psswd');
mysql_select_db('db');
$rows = mysql_query('
SELECT
field1,
field2
FROM table
');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The result is that ";" delimiter is only used in the header of the csv file, not in every row.
Tanks.

Comment: Why didn’t you use the same parameters when printing the rows?

Comment: Why would you exepect fputcsv to 'remember' how you used it last time? You're not specifying any delimiter options for the fputcsv call inside your `while()` loop, so fputcsv is going to use its defaults.

Comment: Ow! forgive me. Didn't realize my silly mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not setting "*dialect*" (delimiter and enclosure) when you iterate trough rows. That is: `';','"'` part. Just use:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
    fputcsv($output, $row,';','"');
}
```

Also for this particular use case [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) may be more appropriate (you avoid having string based indexes and just use numeric ones).

*Side note: [`mysql_` functions family is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1149736), if it's possible try to [replace it with `mysqli_` or `PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).*